# How to prevent function from modifying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the next def:

```
def get_smth
    return @mySmth
end
```

how to make that there should be no way to modify the content through it or through the object it returns?

I thought about getters and setters, but is it a solution?

Comment: You question is bit unclear. Try if this helps `@mySmth.freeze`. [LINK](http://apidock.com/rails/v1.0.0/ActiveRecord/Base/freeze). Also check [THIS LINK](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/readonly%3F)

Comment: @Abhi no, it does not help =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no way to modify the content through it

Do not modify the content in it.

> no way to modify the content through the object it returns

Do not return an object at all, or return a deep copy of an object. Shallow copy, that is returned by `@mySmth.dup` / `@mySmth.clone` might not be sufficient for deeply nested objects.

Comment: сlone works! Thanks!